# How to configure VS code debugger with watch in Nrwl - Fullstack Nest+angular application?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nest, vscode-debugger, nrwl

How can I configure my vs code launch.json to support generated in Nrwl Nest API debugging with watch flag ?

Currently this configuration works for me, but i have to rebuild my application manualy.

```
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api/src/main.ts",
    "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/apps/api/**/*.js"],
    "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
    "skipFiles": [
      "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
      "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
    ]
  },}
```